# exception in thread"main"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java

```
package p1;
public class test_package{
public void show(){
System.out.println("package1");
}
public static void main(String args[]){
test_package t=new test_package();
t.show();
}
}
```

Here is the first class made that has been compiled and package is saved in D: directory...it is running well...
now...

```
package p2;
import p1.test_package;
public class test_package2{
public void show(){
System.out.println("package2 in c:");
}
public static void main(String args[]){
test_package2 T=new test_package2();
test_package T1=new test_package();
T.show();
T1.show();
}
}
```

here is another class importing first class and this is saved in C: directory...
i have set temperory path using cmd command

```
set classpath=D:
```

and compiled it from C: using command
    javac -d C: test_package2.java

when i am running it by command from C:

```
java p2.test_package2
```

it is throwing the error

```
 exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

but the .class file is in p1 package that is in D: drive.....
please help me if anyone has the solution.

Comment: Did you try adding both the dirs where the classes are found in CLASSPATH, like set ClASSPATH=dir1;dir2

Comment: Ya,it didn't work. it's throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It's because JVM is not able to find the test_package in the class_path of test_package2 which is D:. Add test_package to the build path of test_package2. In eclipse you can do this by Right-click on test_package2 > Build Path > Configure Build Path >  Add External Class Folder (or you can zip test_package and use as an external library as well). Now import it in test_package2. It should run.

Comment: i am not using Eclipse... please tell me if u know why it is not finding the package p1 at run time even though path is set.

Comment: Can you list all the steps which you do to execute your program? Also the directory structure.